# How to import node module in TypeScript without type definitions?

Tags: node.js, typescript

When I try to import node.js module in TypeScript like this:

```
import co = require('co');
import co from 'co';
```

without providing type definitions, both lines reports same error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'co'.
```

How to import it correctly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The trick is to use purely JavaScript notation:

```
const co = require('co');
```

Answer (score 13):

Your options are to either import it outside TypeScript's module system (by calling a module API like RequireJS or Node directly by hand) so that it doesn't try to validate it, or to add a type definition so that you can use the module system and have it validate correctly. You can stub the type definition though, so this can be very low effort.

**Using Node (CommonJS) imports directly:**

```
// Note there's no 'import' statement here.
var loadedModule: any = require('module-name');

// Now use your module however you'd like.
```

**Using RequireJS directly:**

```
define(["module-name"], function (loadedModule: any) {
    // Use loadedModule however you'd like
});
```

Be aware that in either of these cases this may mix weirdly with using real normal TypeScript module imports in the same file (you can end up with two layers of module definition, especially on the RequireJS side, as TypeScript tries to manage modules you're also managing by hand). I'd recommend either using just this approach, or using real type definitions.

**Stubbing type definitions:**

Getting proper type definitions would be best, and if those are available or you have time to write them yourself you should definitely should.

If not though, you can just give your whole module the `any` type, and put your module into the module system without having to actually type it:

```
declare module 'module-name' {
    export = <any> {};
}
```

This should allow you to import `module-name` and have TypeScript know what you're talking about. You'll still need to ensure that importing module-name does actually load it successfully at runtime with whatever module system you're using, or it will compile but then fail to actually run.

Comment: Could you explain where should we put this file (when stubbing type definitions), and with which file name? I don't know what is the "module system", I guess typescript does not know about node modules so we should tell where they are.

Comment: How do I create a stub that satisfies an import like `import {Provider} from 'react-redux'`?

Comment: If I put your suggested stub code in the d.ts file I get error TS2714: The expression of an export assignment must be an identifier or qualified name in an ambient context.

Answer (score 5):

I got an error when I used the "Stubbing type definitions" approach in Tim Perry's answer: `error TS2497: Module ''module-name'' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.`

The solution was to rework the stub `.d.ts` file slightly:

```
declare module 'module-name' {
  const x: any;
  export = x;
}
```

And then you can import via:

```
import * as moduleName from 'module-name';
```

Creating your own stub file lowers the barrier to writing out real declarations as you need them.

Comment: This gives me an error TS2306: File 'module-name' is not a module. Note I'm trying to import from a local file directory instead of a module though.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone reading as of 2023 know that you can import it (like in require) but have to specify the extension. For example

```
import './sockets.js'
```

Even though the file is ts, the dist compilation will look for the js extension and the module will be found.

The reason you would want this is to be able to use top level await in your Node file, by specifying type module in the package.json, and module ESNext in your tsconfig.json compilerOptions property.

Answer (score -3):

Just import the module the following way:

```
import 'co';
```