# Unable to Import from Non Angular Modules in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, node-modules

I'm unable to import from a non angular module.

app.components.ts

Folder

Node_Modules -> array- slice

import {array-slice}from 'array-slice' <- Doesn't work

import {Http,Response} from '@angular/http' <-- Works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 import slice = require('array-slice');
```

the `{ Http, Response }` syntax only works for es6 modules with multiple named exports. The following would also work in typescript

```
import * as slice from 'array-slice'
```

but read details here about why this is not the best approach - [New es6 syntax for importing commonjs / amd modules i.e. `import foo = require('foo')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596714/new-es6-syntax-for-importing-commonjs-amd-modules-i-e-import-foo-require)

Comment: Thank you. I keep getting a TS2307: Cannot find module 'array-slice'

Comment: That module is present under node_modules (library root)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I realized that I wasn't using reconfigure.json in my typescript setting in webstorm.

Comment: great - in case anyone else has a similar problem the cannot find module error is usually related to node modules without type definition files - other possible solutions here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000981/how-to-import-node-module-in-typescript-without-type-definitions