# Monaco Editor - node_modules package entry point resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, monaco-editor

I'm trying to load a very basic project using Monaco Editor but I'm having issues resolving node_modules. It seems that the entry point of the project defined in package.json is ignored.

In the example here axios works fine because it has an index.d.ts file at the root of the folder, but any project that doesn't have a .d.ts, or where the main entry point/typings of the file aren't inside the root, don't get resolved. One example of this is delayed-stream where the entry point is inside /lib/delayed_stream.js.

The project has a structure such as:

```
- <root>
  - src
    - index.ts
  - package.json
  - node_modules
    - axios
      - ...
    - delayed-stream
      - ...
```

```
// ./src/index.ts
import axios from 'axios'; // Resolves
import delayedStream from 'delayed-stream'; // Cannot find module 'delayed-stream' or its corresponding type declarations.(2307)
```

All .d.ts files are loaded with:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(data, file);
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(data, file);
monaco.editor.createModel(data, 'typescript', monaco.Uri.parse(file));
```

And all .js, .ts and .json files are loaded with:

```
monaco.editor.createModel(data, language, monaco.Uri.parse(file));
```

I am creating an editor with the same settings as my tsconfig such as:

```
  monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setEagerModelSync(true);
  monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    noSemanticValidation: false,
    noSyntaxValidation: false,
  });
  monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ESNext,
    alwaysStrict: true,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    moduleResolution: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
    module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
    noEmit: true,
    esModuleInterop: true,
    allowJs: true,
    skipLibCheck: true,
    allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
    baseUrl: './'
  });
```

I fear I'm missing something obvious here but I've been searching for days, help very much appreciated.

Comment: So I googled a little bit and it seems there are no type declarations for delayed-stream. So you have to create your own like [here](https://medium.com/@steveruiz/using-a-javascript-library-without-type-declarations-in-a-typescript-project-3643490015f3) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000981/how-to-import-node-module-in-typescript-without-type-definitions)

Comment: I understand that it has no typings but it says it can't find the module at all; I don't get this if I open the same project inside VS Code (and VS Code uses Monaco)

Comment: Your error message is telling you: `Cannot find module 'delayed-stream' OR its corresponding type declarations.(2307)`.

Comment: I understand that but if I replace the import with an import that points to the /lib/delayed_stream file then I get no errors; as I mentioned above the same thing happens with libraries that do have typescript typings but aren't located in the root. It's ignoring the entry point and type file declarations inside package.json

Comment: I would try to change baseUrl to maybe 'src', or declaring the module in a .d.ts file. You can also ts-ignore that line.

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript module resolution may depend on package.json files but Monaco by default does not pass json files to the TypeScript compiler. To fix this, add "package.json" files manually as extra libs.

```
for (const file of files) {
    if (filePath.endsWith('package.json')) {
        monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
            file.content,
            `file://${uri.fsPath}`);
    }
    const model = monaco.editor.createModel(file.content, undefined, file.uri);
}
```