# How to bypass type definitions when importing a module?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to import a module of which I don't know the type definitions and I want to bypass it because I don't really care about type checking.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086843/possible-to-disable-type-checking) ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355244/ignore-cannot-find-module-error-on-typescript))

```
declare module '@module' {
  let _: any;
  export = _ as any;
}
```

But then when I do

```
import { Component } from '@module';
```

I get

```
Module '"@module"' has no exported member 'Component'.
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000981/how-to-import-node-module-in-typescript-without-type-definitions)

```
declare module '@module' {
  export = <any> {};
}
```

But I get both

```
Module '"@module"' has no exported member 'Component'.
```

And (*allowSyntheticDefaultImports is already true*)

```
This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag and referencing its default export.
```

I don't want to use `@ts-nocheck` or `@ts-ignore`. I'm on

```
"typescript": "~4.3.5"
```

How come the first hack isn't working?

EDIT 1: @module is a webpack external (in-browser module)

Comment: Is `@module` a real path? Does it target somewhere?

Comment: No it is an in-browser module